# Retrieve String from Realtime Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve a string from the database but everytime I try it shows an error which says "Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String" a guy on Stackoverflow had my same problem, ii followed the answer that helped him but it's still not working for me

I tried to map the code as an hashmap but it keeps showing me error

This is the model

```java
public ButtonInformationSend(String testoNotifica) {
    TestoNotifica = testoNotifica;
}

public String getTestoNotifica() {
    return TestoNotifica;
}

public void setTestoNotifica(String TestoNotifica) {
    this.TestoNotifica = TestoNotifica;
}
```

and this is the code

```java
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ButtonInformationSend buttonInformationSend = dataSnapshot.getValue(ButtonInformationSend.class);
        creaNotifica(buttonInformationSend);
    }

    @Override public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

the error i get is this Failed to convert value of type `java.util.HashMap` to String

Comment: Hi, Can you post the complete error log?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you cannot directly convert a Hashmap to a string as they are two different types.

```
DataSnaphhot.getValue()
```

returns a hashmap of all the data found at your reference, if your reference points to a node of data in the database. What you need to do is get the hashmap from the data snapshot and then get the relevant data needed from that hashmap, Here is an example of that:

```
            HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                try {
                    String value1 = (String) data.get("Value1");
                    String value2 = (String) data.get("Value2");
                    String value3 = (String) data.get("Value3");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It gives me a null object references

Comment: @DavideVavassori, could you please be more specific on what is giving you null object references?

Answer (score 1):

If you have this database:

```
Users
  id
   name : peter
```

Then the variable `myRef` should be referencing the node `id` to be able to retrieve a `String`, if `myRef` is referencing the root node then you would get the error:

> Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Therefore you should do the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
ref.child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: i tried this method but it gives me an error "Null Object references"

Comment: we dont know what you added and we dont know the structure of your database, maybe show us what you did exactly so we can help you